# Map that sends a $2\times 2$ matrix to a Mobius transformation is a homomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

The set of all Mobius transformations is a group of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{C} \cup {\infty}$ onto itself. All Mobius transformations have inverses. How can I show the map that sends the $2\times 2$ matrix $$ \left[ \begin{array}{ c c } a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] $$ to the Mobius transformation $$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ is a homomorphism of $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ of invertible $2\times 2$ complex matrices onto the set of all Mobius transformations? I know we have a map $\phi : GL(2, \mathbb{C}) \to \textrm{set of all Mobius transformations}$ and I need to check that $\phi (AB) = \phi (A) \circ \phi (B)$ ($\circ$ since Mobius transformations are compositions).

Most of my issue in understanding this problem is the notation. We did not learn in this class what a homomorphism is, and I didn't know what $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ meant until I looked it up. I'm not really that comfortable with groups or abstract algebra, but in this case it doesn't really seem all that necessary.

Comment: Have you tried computing $\phi(A)(\phi(B)(z))$ and $\phi(AB)(z)$ and comparing them?

Comment: I don't really understand how to compute such a thing. $\phi$ as I understand it is a mapping from a matrix to an expression, am I correct? So I'm not sure what $\phi (B)(z)$ means.

Comment: If $B=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, then $\phi(B)(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$.

Comment: If $B$ is that same matrix, then what is $\phi (B) =$ (without the $(z)$ part)?

Comment: $\phi(B)=z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Or maybe I should write the (equivalent) $\phi(B)=x\mapsto\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ to avoid using $z$ again.

Comment: I thought $\phi$ was a mapping with matrices in the domain. Why do we have a mapping from $z$ as the domain?

Comment: $B$ is a matrix.  $\phi(B)$ is a Mobius transformation.  So for $z \in \mathbb C \cup \infty$, $\phi(B)(z) \in \mathbb C \cup \infty$ is the result of doing that transformation to $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, all you need to do is check that $\phi(A) \circ \phi(B) = \phi(AB)$.  As the comments above have explained, $\phi$ is a function that takes a matrix $M$ and gives you a function (in particular, a Möbius transformation) $\phi(M) :\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$.

We write
$$
A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{a'&b'\\c'&d'}
$$
We can describe $\phi(B)$ as
$$
[\phi(B)](z) = \frac{a'z + b'}{c'z + d'}
$$
and so 
$$
[\phi(A) \circ \phi(B)](z) = 
[\phi(A)]([\phi(B)](z)) = \\
\frac{a\frac{a'z + b'}{c'z + d'} + b}{c\frac{a'z + b'}{c'z + d'} + d}
$$
you want to show that this is the same as $\phi(AB)$.  In particular, 
$$
AB = \pmatrix{
aa' + bc' & ab' + bd'\\
ca' + dc' & cb' + dd'}
$$
so that
$$
[\phi(AB)](z) = \frac{(aa' + bc')z + (ab' + bd')}{(ca' + dc')z + (cb' + dd')}
$$
your goal, then, is to show that these two functions, $[\phi(AB)](z)$ and $[\phi(A)\circ  \phi(B)](z)$, are equal.

---

As for "why this is necessary": nothing in math is strictly necessary.  However, this homomorphism is useful since it allows us to say *everything* about the composition of Möbius functions in terms of matrices, and there are a lot of things we already know how to do with matrices.

For example, we can use this to derive a neat formula for the inverse of a transformation, and we can use this to evaluate things like $f \circ \cdots \circ f$ where $f$ is a transformation.